# Reduce hanging when trying to sum up grouped values

Tags: project-reactor, reactive-streams

I'm trying use a Project Reactor chain set up to collect and group values to finally sum them up by group. The collection is split into two parts and blocking.

In a simplified example I'm able to reproduce the problem. First I gather some generic data in createWrappers() which reads data from a the network (blocking calls). As data is retrieved objects are emitted. in the second step details are gathered from a different blocking network location and that information is added to the wrapper part. Then data gets transformed into a list of details, grouped by the details key and finally summed up by details key. In the end a map should be produced which looks like this (values are specific for the testcase):

```
key         value
------------------
detail-0    1000
detail-1    2000
detail-2    3000
...
```

As soon as I add the block() to the reduce() part everything hangs in the sample code below:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.FluxSink;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestBlockingIssue
{
    @Test
    public void testBlockingMap()
    {
        final Flux<Wrapper> source = Flux.create( sink -> createWrappers( 1000, sink ) );

        final Map<String, BigDecimal> block = source.parallel( 10 ).runOn( Schedulers.boundedElastic() )
                .map( wrapper -> enhanceWrapper( wrapper, 100 ) )
                .flatMap( wrapper -> Flux.fromIterable( wrapper.detailsList ) )
                .sequential()
                .groupBy( details -> details.detailKey )
                .cache()
                .collectMap( group -> group.key(), group -> group.reduce( new BigDecimal( 0 ), ( x, y ) -> x.add( y.value ) ).block() ).block();

        System.out.println( block );
    }

    private Wrapper enhanceWrapper( final Wrapper wrapper, final int count )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
        {
            wrapper.detailsList.add( new Details( "detail-" + i, new BigDecimal( i +1 ) ) );
        }
        return wrapper;
    }

    private void createWrappers( final int count, final FluxSink<Wrapper> sink )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
        {
            sink.next( new Wrapper( "Wrapper-" + i ) );
        }
        sink.complete();
    }

    private class Details
    {
        final String detailKey;

        final BigDecimal value;

        private Details( final String detailKey, final BigDecimal value )
        {
            this.detailKey = detailKey;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    private class Wrapper
    {
        final String lookupKey;

        final List<Details> detailsList = new ArrayList<>();

        private Wrapper( final String lookupKey )
        {
            this.lookupKey = lookupKey;
        }
    }
}
```

How could I resolve the issue with the hanging chain or which alternatives do I have to generate the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs when using groupBy with too much groups and downstream isn't fast enough to consume the group. In your sample you should not block in the collect map but you should consume the group before collecting like:

```java
final Map<String, BigDecimal> block = source.parallel( 10 ).runOn( Schedulers.boundedElastic() )
    .map( wrapper -> enhanceWrapper( wrapper, 100 ) )
    .flatMap( wrapper -> Flux.fromIterable( wrapper.detailsList ) )
    .sequential()
    .groupBy( details -> details.detailKey )
    .cache()
    .flatMap(g -> g.reduce( new BigDecimal( 0 ), ( x, y ) -> x.add( y.value ) ).map(v -> Tuples.of(g.key(), v)))
    .collectMap(Tuple2::getT1, Tuple2::getT2)
    .block();
```

So now downstream is fast enough but you might need to adjust concurrency depending on the number of group. And be sure that you have a low number of groups.